# NameError in ArticlesController#create undefined local variable or method `article_params' for #<ArticlesController:Did you mean? article_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting this error when I create my articles:

error: NameError in ArticlesController#create
undefined local variable or method `article_params' for # Did you mean? article_path

image of error : [image]

my code :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if  @article.save
      flash[:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"
      redirect_to (@article)
    else
      render :new
    end

    private

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put article params outside of create

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @article = Article.new 
   end

   def create
     @article = Article.new(article_params)
     if  @article.save
       flash[:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"
       redirect_to (@article)
     else
       render :new
     end 
   end

  # this is show method
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

    private 
    def article_params 
       params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

Comment: Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for ArticlesController

Comment: just added in my answer how add show action in article controller

Answer (score 0):

I think the create action was not properly closed,therefore you have the article_params method inside the create action,delete the 'end' at the last line and add an 'end' to the create action,its a syntax error. like this

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

      def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
        if  @article.save
          flash[:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"
          redirect_to (@article)
        else
          render :new
        end
        end

        private
        def article_params
          params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
        end
      end
```